# using image component of asp.net in javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, image

I found a `javascript` [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610321/1427849) that get and set the dimension of image .
By reference this link , I write the code in my `asp.net` web site likes this ,

```
<img runat="server" id="MyImage" onload="if( this.width >  
this.height ){ this.width = 400; this.height = 600} else {this.width = 600;   
this.height=400}" />
```

What I want to know is how to write this `javascript` code in this `<script>` tag

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function setDimension() {

   }
</script>
```

Comment: If my `javascript` code is wrong , Kindly show me the correct code :), Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function setDimension(me) {
  var th= document.getElementById(me);
   if( th.width >  
th.height ){ th.width = 400; th.height = 600} else {th.width = 600;   
th.height=400}
   }
</script>
```

ASPX Code:

```
<img runat="server" id="MyImage"  />
```

In code behind, as onload is also a server event, you need to add custom attribute to server image control

```
 MyImage.Attributes["onload"] = "setDimension(this.id)";
```